# _JAVA_OPTIONS does not set -Xmx

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, windows-10

I am trying to get Elasticsearch running on my windows machine, but getting an error, "Could not create the Java virtual machine."

Windows 10, 32GB RAM, 64bit 
JVM 1.8.0_201 
Elasticsearch 6.6.1 installed with msi installer, not as a service.

Elasticsearch is asking for just over 3GB heap size, so I have set (and also tried commenting out) jvm.options with:

```
-Xmx4096m
-Xms4096m
```

But then I get the dreaded JVM error.  I'm sure the error is caused by the jvm heap size being too small.  So I have set the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS to " -Xms512m -Xmx6144m".

If I run:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

I get:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx6144m
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
 uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                        = 0                                   {product}
 uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                      = 87241520                            {product}
 uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 536870912                          {product}
 uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold               = 134217728                           {product}
 uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2147483648                         {product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 0                                   {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 0                                   {pd product}
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

You can see it "picks up" _JAVA_OPTIONS, but the MaxHeapSize is still around 2GB.  I have also tried running elastic search as admin and forcing jvm to run as admin, but this hasn't helped.  This appears to be a common problem, but answers are limited and none have worked for me.

**EDIT**
I have Elasticsearch running on Ubuntu 18 server with the same java and ES versions.

ES is set to:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

and jvm has MaxHeapSize=1056309248 (1GB).  And it's working fine.

I don't understand why the Windows installation is asking for 3GB heap size and why the jvm can't supply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html) says that the env variable name should be `ES_JAVA_OPTS`.
You can also just leave it out and rely on default max heap size which should be ~8GB in your case (1/4 of available memory).

Comment: I would swear I tried it without the environment variable, but I must have tried it when I was dealing with an earlier error.  It works now.  Thanks!